# CXF Corba and Namingservice

Tags: cxf, corba

I'm trying to build a service that also (beside of SOAP) uses CORBA/IIOP for communication. I followed the (CXF) CORBA Bank Demo and manged it to get it running. But despite of what is written in the README-File it needs no corba naming service.

What I need is, that the server registers it's service at a corba nameing service and the client looks up the server through the nameing service. Is there any way to achieve this goal ?

Comment: There are dozens of examples on the web and as part of the various CORBA distributions that demonstrate how to use the naming service. Would help if you could at least tell which programming language you are using.

Answer (score 1):

The bank demo uses a file to store the reference.   The "corba/hello_world" sample uses a "corbaname" url in the wsdl to force the use of a naming service.   Check that one or the "bank_ws_addressing" sample which also uses the corbaname urls.